# This code seems to return all rows

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

```
match match = myRepo.GetAll()
    .Where(m => m.personId == personId)
    .Where(m => m.companyId == companyId).FirstOrDefault();
```

now there are over 1m records and it takes ages. I refactored it to do a single linq query and it runs instantly. This suggests the the myRepo.GetAll() returns everything then its looping over every row to do the where's rather than do it at the db level.

GetAll looks like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Paging p = null)
{
    // Get the set as a queryable.
    IQueryable<T> q = _db.Set<T>();

    if(p != null)
    {
        p.TotalCount = q.Count();
        q = q.Skip(p.StartAt).Take(p.PageSize);
    }

    // Return the enumerable.
    return q.AsEnumerable<T>();
}
```

I just want to sanity check if my theory is correct, some of the guys think because its IEnumerable it shouldnt do this, but its returning that first then has to loop over in the local function in my opinion as the where's are outside the linq query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that your `GetAll` method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` (rather than `IQueryable<T>`) means that your `Where` call is using LINQ to Objects, not EF. In other words, that query is fetching *all* the data locally, and filtering it in your process. That's not good.

Consider changing `GetAll` to:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll(Paging p = null)
{
    // Get the set as a queryable.
    IQueryable<T> q = _db.Set<T>();

    if(p != null)
    {
        p.TotalCount = q.Count();
        q = q.Skip(p.StartAt).Take(p.PageSize);
    }

    return q;
}
```

Then you're still in "queryable land". Note that this is *still* flawed though, as you'd want to apply paging *after* any other queries, not before. So you might actually want to just have a method returning `_db.Set<T>()`, and then have a separate extension method for paging. (I'm nervous of the fact that your paging implementation requires you to count the full results, mind you...)

Comment: Counting all the results lets you indicate how many pages there are to the user, I guess.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, but doing it unconditionally seems like a bad idea.

Comment: This is a better solution than what I implemented and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the rest of that paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

using `AsEnumberable` you will get everything in the memory and the query is applied after this.

Comment: This would be the same even if the `.AsEnumerable<T>();` was removed.